# Filter data frame rows with character string in R

Tags: r, dataframe, character

I have a large DF compiled from a list with 4 columns. Please see an example table below:

```
   Date         Depth        Pressure        Level
   2023-05-01   65           NA              DRY
   2023-06-01   67           45              45
   2023-07-01   66           NA              NO ACCESS
   2023-08-01   68           56              60
   2023-09-01   68           55              NOT ABLE TO MEASURE LEVEL
```

As you can see, there are some rows that do not have numerical strings in them. Any row that has a NA in the Pressure column will have a character string in the Level column. Additionally, there are some rows in the level column with a character string even though there is a value in its associated row in the pressure column.

How do I go about changing any character string in rows to NA. Please note the character strings presented above are an example. There is a wide varity.

Is there anyway to mutate character strings generally to NA in DF?

Comment: `df$Level[grepl("\\D", df$Level)] <- NA`. The `\\D` is "non-digit character", so it will match anything other than 0-9 (no neg/pos, no decimals/dots, etc).

Comment: You could coerce `Level` to numeric. Anything that cannot be converted will automatically be changed to `NA` with a warning. `as.numeric(DF$Level)` (assuming you do not need `Level` to be character).